# Simple "if" statement inside of function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, survey

I need help. I am doing a project and am creating a simple survey. The code I have should work. Upon pressing the "yes" button, it should add 1 to the "artscore" variable. Then when I press "submit" it should check if the variable is over 1 and if it says "You are an artist" and if it isn't bigger than 1 it should say "You are something different". However whenever I do this and press submit it always says "You are something different", even when I have clicked "yes" multiple times. It should work but it doesn't. I am a complete beginner and the answer may be very simple. I have made multiple prototypes but I want to figure out how to make a survey this way.

Thank you for any help.

BTW the HTML part of this code got taken away. This website wouldn't let me put it in. This is just the javascript part without the beginning script tag. The beginning HTML just had some buttons which when click ran the two functions. The yes button runs the `artFunction` function and the submit button runs the `submitFunction` function. I also don't know why the code below is in two parts. Thanks for any help on why this code doesn't work.

```
var artscore = 0;


function artFunction(){

   artscore = artscore + 1;

}

function submitFunction(){

    if (artscore > 1){
     alert("You are an artist");
    } else {
    alert("You are something different");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are not invoking the function. What is happening is that you have defined the function, but not invoking it. You have register the button's onclick event with these functions. Please edit the post to include your html code which has the button.

Comment: So what is the condition if it is exactly 1? The artscore will equal 1 and not be greater than 1 and therefore say "You are something different".

Comment: The html would be helpful to understand your issue. Try to add a jsfiddle if you cannot add html here

Comment: Just past in the relevant part of the HTML, the select it all, and then press the code button in the format area of this site. It looks like this {}.

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
  <h1>What type of field are you interested in?</h1>
  <p>Take this questionnaire to find out!</p>
  
  <form id="quiz">
 <h2> ART1 <h2>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="artFunction();" value="Yes"/>
<button type="button">No</button> 

</form>

<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="submitFunction();" value="Submit"/>
 

</div>

Comment: This is my html. I am sorry that it is all scruntched up but I dont know how to add more to this tread or whatever without commenting.

Comment: Was it the  //console.log(artscore); part that made it work. And if so, how would I make it for more variables. The "You are something else" is just a place holder. I want to make a longer if/else statement. I want the function to go through around 8 variables. If I did this. Would I have to change the  //console.log(artscore); part of the code becuase it  wouldn't just be the artscore variable in the function anymore. It would also be like 7 other variables. Sorry if I dont make any sence.

Comment: Could I even make an if/else statement that long?

Comment: @user10693934, please read comment I added to my answer, remove all unnecessary comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `>=`, you are using >, because of > when ever you click Art button first time it is showing **"You are something different"** message instead of **"You are an artist"**

```js
var artscore = 0;


function artFunction(){
   //console.log(artscore);
   artscore = artscore + 1;

}

function submitFunction(){
    //console.log(artscore);
    if (artscore >= 1){
     alert("You are an artist");
    } else {
    alert("You are something different");
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>What type of field are you interested in?</h1> 
  <p>Take this questionnaire to find out!</p> 
  <h2> ART1 <h2> 
  <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="artFunction();" value="Yes"/>
  <button type="button">No</button>
  <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="submitFunction();" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: @user10693934, writing longer if/else means what? if answer work for you then please accept it. //console.log(artscore); is not what it helped to work. Please read description of answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure whether this will solve the problem, but the problem may be in the if statement in the submit function. You are currently checking for if artscore is greater than 1, but in your art function you are adding one to artscore. You should instead check for if artscore is greater than **or equal to** 1. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest being more specific with your code i.e.

```
function submitFunction(){
    if (artscore >= 1){
        alert("You are an artist");
    } else if (artscore < 1){
        alert("You are something different");
    } else {
        alert("An error has occurred!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When your else part will execute?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (artscore > 1)
```

to

```
if (artscore >= 1)
```

and also check if you are calling the funcation.